# Logical expression evaluation in Xpath

Tags: xpath, marklogic

I have an XPATH expression of the following sort that's expected to return a boolean value:

```
 xs:boolean(expression1 or expression2 or expression3)
```

If `expression1` returns `true`, would the other expressions be evaluated?

In any case could any one point me to examples of how complex logical expressions are written  efficiently in XPATH?

BTW: I am running the XPATH on MarkLogic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath 1.0 it's defined that the expressions are evaluated in order, left to right, until one of them returns true.

But the presence of xs:boolean (which is redundant) in your expression suggests you are using XPath 2.0, and XPath 2.0 processors are allowed to evaluate the subexpressions in any order. This is to allow database-style optimization: one of the subexpressions might be much faster to execute (or more likely to return true) than the others, perhaps because of database indexes, so an optimizer will evaluate that one first. But any decent optimizer will stop evaluation after the first expression that evaluates to "true".

I can't tell you specifically what MarkLogic does.

For anyone else trying this, the "or" operator in XPath must be lower-case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to change the or's to smaller case.

Answer (score 2):

In light of Michael Kay's comments on optimization, I can't say for sure whether MarkLogic chooses  expression to evaluate first or goes left to right, but you can see how a particular XPath is evaluated. In Query Console (usually localhost:8000/qconsole), type in an expression, click the Profile tab, and Run.

```
//foo[xs:boolean(1 = 1 or 2 = 3)]
```

The profile tab shows that "1 = 1" is evaluated and "2 = 3" is not.